# troubleshooting raspberry pi booting with the green led light

Tags: boot-issues

**Update**  : I've downloaded and copied the [NOOBS](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads) images from here. Checked the hash, and when I run it on the Pi the green light blinks once and then only the red light is on. Nothing else happens from then on.

Apparently there are **logs** somewhere? Where can I find info about the logs? I have a windows, freebsd and osx machine around.

---

I just bought [adafruit pi starter kit](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1014) and downloaded occidentalis. Unfortunately it doesn't boot. The power light goes on, the green light(ACT) flashes brightly for a while then goes mostly off.

With the rains and flaky internet it's taken a while but I've checked the md5 of my image.

I burnt it into a micro sd on windows (tried both with [fedora arm installer](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_ARM_Installer#Windows_Vista_.26_7) and [win disk imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/)).

I've looked at a variety of posts here, on raspberrypi.org and the PI troubleshooting page here: http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting

I still have to test another card, and possibly another distribution.

In the meantime this is what I want to know:

1. I saw this [2011 thread @raspberrypi.org](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=8725#p103338) and they talked about a `start.elf` file in this [github repo](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware) and how it should match the armxxx_start.elf. I **want to know** whether this **still applies**?  Is there a way to play/check the *.elf files to fix my issue?
2. This [troubleshooting page](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern) says :

   ```
   3 flashes: start.elf not found
   4 flashes: start.elf not launched
   7 flashes: kernel.img not found
   ```

   Does this also still apply? My ACT light flashes brightly in the beginning, then stops completely after a minute or so.

Any ideas would be extremely appreciated.

---

I've done the basic things like check for files in the SD card, tried with no monitor plugged in. I don't have my multimeter now, so I'll check with that soon and I'm going to try the NOOBS image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after hours of troubleshooting, I fixed it by changing the config.txt. I uncommented this:

```
hdmi_safe=1
```

And it worked!

Was an interesting experience troubleshooting all in all!

**Info:** Use `safe mode` settings to try to boot with maximum hdmi compatibility. This is the same as the combination of: `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`, `hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080`, `config_hdmi_boost=4`, `hdmi_group=2`, `hdmi_mode=4`, `disable_overscan=0`, `overscan_left=24`, `overscan_right=24`, `overscan_top=24`, `overscan_bottom=24`. See http://elinux.org/RPiconfig.

Comment: My Pi4 doesn't even load, how do I edit that

Comment: @Si8 I realize this is a bit late but here is an article about several ways to edit the config.txt file, https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/edit-boot-config-file-raspberry-pi/ including how to do it with a PC using Notepad as your editor. In a nutshell, you need to access the SD card using a memory card reader, go to the boot partition, then use Notepad or other text editor to open and modify the `config.txt` file. Make sure that after saving the changes, you properly eject the card to ensure the drive is updated and not corrupted.