# No display output from Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

The Pi is connected to the power supply (5V 2000mA) and the HDMI is connected to monitor (1600 x 900). The status of my Pi is as follows:

- Red light is solid
- Green light blinks randomly
- Ethernet port also seems to work (The light is blinking)

I'm not getting any output from my monitor. I have read the following:

- [No display on tv when raspberry pi boots](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9822/no-display-on-tv-when-raspberry-pi-boots)
- [troubleshooting raspberry pi booting with the green led light](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8070/troubleshooting-raspberry-pi-booting-with-the-green-led-light?rq=1)

I haven't had any luck even after reading these.

Comment: From the behaviour of your LEDs, it sounds like the Pi is booting normally. Couple of questions: Is the Pi accessible over SSH? Do you have access to a second display you can test the Pi with?

Comment: I have a tv to test it with

Comment: As a quick test, hook it up to the TV. If it works the problem is specific to your monitor. If it doesn't there's likely a problem with the Pi's HDMI configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your settings in **config.txt** file in boot partition. Set:

```
hdmi_safe=0
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=83
```

Reboot your device and check. This will set your HDMI output to 1600x900 with reduced blanking. 
For more information loot at: http://elinux.org/RPiconfig

Comment: Will unplugging my pi from the power supply damage it?

Comment: No, you can feel free to unplug it.

Comment: No luck It didn't work

Comment: Tell more about your monitor. Model, refresh rate.

Comment: It is a LG monitor with a refresh rate of 75Hz

Comment: Try:
`hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=6
hdmi_force_hotplug=1 
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080 
config_hdmi_boost=4
 disable_overscan=0
overscan_left=24
overscan_right=24
 overscan_top=24
 overscan_bottom=24`

Comment: Not of any help

Comment: Try to combine configuration related to your 75Hz refresh rate using this guide: http://elinux.org/RPiconfig

Comment: The red light also blinks with the green one now

Comment: A blinking red power LED indicates problems with the power supply. Check your connections, cable, and power supply.

Comment: Incorrect! Don't ever unplug it without a proper shutdown. This can corrupt the SD card and possibly give you issues in the future.